# how to think about reducing the dimensions of the array along some axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I don't understand how to think in selecting a specific axis doing `np.mean` or `np.max`
I know already axis= 0 along the rows and axis =1 along columns but how could selecting this one axis help me in doing the next step ?

```
ds  = load_iris()
X = ds.data[:, :2]



neighbors = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
distances, indices = neighbors.kneighbors(X)
dist = np.sum((np.repeat(X, k=3, axis=1).reshape(-1, k, 2) - X[indices]) ** 
2, axis=2)
k_dist = distances[indices].max(axis=2)
```

but in another example

```
 dist_ = np.mean(distances, axis=1)
```

like in solid geometry what is the goal of chosing the mean acrross the row or acrross the column? in what way will it afect it for the next time and how to know that you're chosing the right axis to do it ?

Comment: If you want to find black horizontal lines across an image of a newspaper, you might check if `np.mean(image, axis=1)` is low meaning there are lots of dark (nearly zero-valued) pixels across a row. If you wanted to find vertical lines between articles, you might look at axis=0.

Comment: It's easier to think about axis for 1d (only one axis to choose from) or 3d (choose one leave two).  Extend that to 2d, where reducing one, leaving one, is harder to describe in words.

Comment: @Mark Setchell can you pls explain like what does the above code represent? and is this reducing  n_samples or n_features?